# PHP database angularjs

Tags: php, database, angularjs, post

I am trying to send some data to a MySQL database. Nothing happens when I press the button to add new users. I do not see any errors so I do not know where it goes wrong. Could someone help me with this?

## index.html

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
      <head>
        <title> AngularJS Sample</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script  src="js/controllers/userController.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="container" style="margin:0px 100px 0px 500px;">
        <fieldset style="width:200px;">
          <legend>Add Friend</legend>
            <form name="addcustomer" method="POST">
                First Name:<input type="text" ng-model="newFriend.fname" name="firstname"/>
                <br/>
                Last Name :<input type="text" ng-model="newFriend.lname" name="lastname"/>
                <br/>
                <button ng-click="addNewFriend()" name="add">Add Friend</button>
            </form>
          </fieldset>
       </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

## insert.php

```
if(isset($_POST['add']))
        {
            $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

            $fstname = mysql_real_escape_string($data->fname);
            $lstname = mysql_real_escape_string($data->lname);

            $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die('Could not connect: ' . 
            mysql_error());
            mysql_select_db('angularjs') or die (mysql_error());

            mysql_query("INSERT INTO friends (fname,lname) VALUES ('$fstname', '$lstname')"); 
            Print "Your information has been successfully added to the database."; 

    }
```

## userController.js

```
app.controller('userController', ["$scope","$http", function($scope,$http){
    $scope.addNewFriend = function(add){
    var data = {
        fname:$scope.newFriend.fname,
        lname:$scope.newFriend.lname
    };


    $http.post("php/insert.php",data)
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
        console.log("inserted Successfully");
    });

    $scope.friends.push($scope.data);
    $scope.newFriend = {
        fname:"",
        lname:""
    };
};   

}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.controller('userController', ["$scope","$http", function($scope,$http){
    $scope.newFriend = {
        fName:"",
        lName:""
    };
    $scope.friends = new Array();
    $scope.addNewFriend = function(){
        $http.post("php/insert.php",$scope.newFriend)
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                $scope.friends.push($scope.data);
                console.log("inserted Successfully");
        });
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Yes, it did work. I still had to delete the if(isset($_POST['add'])). After I deleted it, it worked like a charm! Thanks!